# A word for the property of being either prefix or postfix

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm looking for a word that describes the property of an operator being prefix or postfix, so I can write 'In expression `x++`, the _____ of `++` is "postfix"'.

I thought of using 'fixity', but that seems to be about operator associativity (at least that's what I managed to gather from usage of 'fixity' in this context; the other, non-technical, definition of 'fixity' makes searching for the technical one pretty difficult).

Comment: 'affixation type/class'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This seems fitting. If you make this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: They're not fixed phrases, nor even loose collocations, as far as I've been able to discover, so I won't big them up with an 'answer'. I think they're transparent enough to use.

Comment: Since *prefixes* and *postfixes* are both *affixes*, if you want to coin an *-ity* word, it should probably be *affixity*.